# how to get a public feed of a particular user in facebook ios

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the public JSON feed of a particular user. I was successful in getting the JSON feed using `access_token` and without using `FBConnect` but the feed returns the entire wall post; What I want is to get the feeds of a particular user say feeds posted by "MuzikGarage".Is it possible?

Below is the json url.

https://graph.facebook.com/MuzikGarage/posts?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET

Fan page
   http://www.facebook.com/MuzikGarage

Comment: This is not programming related question, read to API doc and do some trial and error! for convenience use apigee, if you want.

Comment: @owl - It **is** related to programming for the Facebook platform.

Comment: could u send me a api document url

Comment: You should never post your access token here - someone can take that token and access anything they want...

Comment: @Lix:sorry  i was little desperate to find the answer.ma deadline is tmrw.

Comment: I understand that you were rushing - but as it stands right now, that token is valid and should some "bad" person obtain it - he can really really mess up your page/application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data -

```
 "data": [
      {
         "id": "171866742868832_401252956589556",
         "from": {
            "name": "MuzikGarage",
            "category": "Musician/band",
            "id": "171866742868832"
         },
         ...
      },
      {
         "id": "171866742868832_476648515696413",
         "from": {
            "name": "MuzikGarage",
            "category": "Musician/band",
            "id": "171866742868832"
         },
        ...
      },
      {
         "id": "171866742868832_379816898740481",
         "from": {
            "name": "MuzikGarage",
            "category": "Musician/band",
            "id": "171866742868832"
         },
         ...
       }
      ...
      ]
```

You can see that, for each post there is a `from` object containing details about who posted that specific message.  What you could do is iterate over all the results you get and inspect the `data['from']['id']` field to see if that post was made by the page.

Comment: i want to parse the message send only by MuzikGarage..could u gimme me an example..will be really greatful

Comment: I can't give you an example because I don't know objective-c.  Just loop over the data and look at the `from` property of each element.  It should be pretty basic...